# CSS set height and width but have div resize in a flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a modal dialog that auto resizes and overflows the content inside.  However, the modal content keeps overflowing the container and wont show scrollbars.  It's because the container height is explicitly set, but I want the inner content to stretch it to it's max-size.  I don't know of any tricks to get it to work.

---

#### What I originally came up with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>

        window.onload = function () {
            var contentString = 'ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ';
            window.el = document.getElementById('content')
            function toggleContent() {
                if (el.innerText == "") el.innerText = contentString;
                else el.innerText = "";
            }
            window.toggleContent = toggleContent;
            el.innerText = contentString;
        }

    </script>
    <style>
    * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        #fixed {
            position: fixed;
            top: 12px;
            right: 24px;
            transform: scale(2.0);
        }

        .overlay {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            align-content: center;
            background-color: gray;
        }

        section {
            background-color: white;
            border: 3px solid red;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 36em;
            height: 24em;
            max-width: 95vw;
            max-height: 95vh;
        }

        p {
            border: 3px solid green;
            word-break: break-all;
        }

        header {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            align-content: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="overlay">
        <section>
            <header>
                <span>Header</span>
                <span>
                    X
                </span>
            </header>
            <p id="content">Initial Content</p>
            <footer>Footer</footer>
        </section>
    </div>
    <button id="fixed" onclick="toggleContent()">Toggle</button>
</body>

</html>
```

---

#### An example of what it should look like in all four cases (no content, full content, large and small)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var contentString = 'ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent';
  window.el = document.getElementsByClassName('filled');

  function toggleContent() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(el, f => {
      if (f.innerText == "Content") f.innerText = contentString;
      else f.innerText = "Content";
    })
  }
  window.toggleContent = toggleContent;
  toggleContent();
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.panel {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.panel.one,
.panel.two {
  width: 50%;
  height: 400px;
}

.panel.three,
.panel.four {
  width: 14%;
  height: 400px;
}

article {
  /* overlay */
  background-color: gray;
}

section {
  /* modal window */
  border: 3px solid red;
  background-color: white;
}

p {
  /* content */
  border: 3px solid green;
  word-break: break-all;
}

article {
  /* overlay, all behave the same pretty much */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.one section {
  /* modal window */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
}

.one p {
  /* content */
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.three section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 90%;
  height: 40%;
}

.two section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 95%;
  max-width: 95%;
}

.two p {
  max-height: 95%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.four section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 95%;
  max-width: 88%;
}

.four p {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="panel one">
    <article>
      <!-- overlay -->
      <section>
        <!-- modal window -->
        <p>Content</p>
        <!-- body content -->
      </section>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="panel two">
    <article>
      <section>
        <p class="filled">Content</p>
      </section>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="panel three">
    <article>
      <section>
        <p>Content</p>
      </section>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="panel four">
    <article>
      <section>
        <p class="filled">Content</p>
      </section>
    </article>
  </div>
  <button id="fixed" onclick="toggleContent()">Toggle</button>
</body>

</html>
```

---

#### Summary

Is there a way to do what I want with pure HTML/CSS ?  I cannot find a way to overcome the fact that `max-height: 100%` only respects explicit definitions of `height`

Comment: Can you explain a bit better? I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve. You want to set the height of the container, but then also you want it to grow taller if the text height is taller than the box?

Comment: @RobKwasowski, Your example isn't growing for me in chrome.  I'm on my main development machine, let me rework the question.  Sorry.

Comment: Extremely close, the height adjusts properly but the width doesn't.  An interesting issue.  I'm about to add a SO snippit to my post that has an example of what I'm needing.

Comment: I've changed `width` to `min-width` https://jsfiddle.net/liquidmetalrob/g12p3s5w/5/ Is this what you want? I've put the change into my answer below as well

Comment: I think that's it.  I've iterated this so many times today I can't figure out what I was doing differently and why it wasn't working.  I'll tentatively select yours as the answer and review it when I implement this in my project.  Thanks Rob!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need to do is go to your second example, `broken & overflow-y-scroll` and change the `height` property to `min-height`. Is that the effect that you want?

```css
* {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        #fixed {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            transform: scale(2.0) translate(-0.5)
        }

        .overlay {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            align-content: center;
            background-color: gray;
        }

        section {
            background-color: white;
            border: 3px solid red;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            min-width: 36em;
            min-height: 24em;
            max-width: 95vw;
            max-height: 95vh;
        }

        p {
            border: 3px solid green;
            word-break: break-all;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        header {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            align-content: center;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>

        window.onload = function () {
            var contentString = 'ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent ';
            window.el = document.getElementById('content')
            function toggleContent() {
                if (el.innerText == "") el.innerText = contentString;
                else el.innerText = "";
            }
            window.toggleContent = toggleContent;
            el.innerText = contentString;
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="overlay">
        <section>
            <header>
                <span>Header</span>
                <span>
                    X
                </span>
            </header>
            <p id="content">Initial Content</p>
            <footer>Footer</footer>
        </section>
    </div>
    <button id="fixed" onclick="toggleContent()">Toggle</button>
</body>

</html>
```